# htaccess Redirect adding a prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a pretty massive 301 redirect file, but there are a few specific pages where it seems to be redirecting to the incorrect page. For example I have a section that deals with the 11/14 pages below:

```
    Redirect 301 /2016/11/14/ /14
    Redirect 301 /2016/11/14/5-worst-cities-preppers-doomsday/ /5-worst-cities-preppers-doomsday
    Redirect 301 /2016/11/14/5-worst-cities-preppers-doomsday/feed/ /sitemap
    Redirect 301 /2016/11/14/make-winter-tea-great-drink-comfort-health/ /make-winter-tea-great-drink-comfort-health
    Redirect 301 /2016/11/14/make-winter-tea-great-drink-comfort-health/feed/ /sitemap
```

The problem is visiting any of the old urls just redirects the URL to one with a weird prefix like below:

```
1114/5-worst-cities-preppers-doomsday/feed/
```

I am at a loss here because "1114" doesn't appear in my .htaccess file anywhere.

Comment: The rewriting module offers "rewrite logging" which allows to understand in depth every details about the process inside your rewriting engine. But the `Redirect` directive is implemente by the alias module which does not offer such thing.

Comment: Show us your full .htaccess file, maybe it goes wrong in a different place than the handful of directives you have shown so far. Btw., are you aware that `Redirect` does _prefix-based_ matching? The first one of those you got there, would catch _everything_ that starts with `/2016/11/14/` already, so the following ones should never get to apply.

Comment: I did not know that! I am sure that is what is happening I'll have to go out and remove all the numbered page redirects. I can not post the whole file as it is 4200 lines. Basically I no longer use wordpress and a lot of the backlinks I have go to stupid wordpress links like tag/2016/name-of-the-page which is no longer valid. I would love to know a better way if there is one.